# Combining sqlite data into second table when grouped by name

Tags: sqlite

I have a database that is the output for a python script involving a basic game. When the code saves to the database, it saves it to a table called points with the data: name, account_name, time, score. What I want is for the data be saved into a second table when sorted by name, I will then do the same with account_name. Some of the points table:

`name   |account_name | time                | score
 oliver |Oliver       | 10:29:14-01:04:2017 | 250
 oliver |Oliver       | 10:29:20-01:04:2017 | 500
 dave   |Oliver       | 10:29:34-01:04:2017 | 250`

What I want is for the data to be sorted into a table called name, where the score is totalled for all records with the same name and a column keeps track of how many entries have been merged(In this case, it will be equal to number of games played). For example:

```
name  | totalpoints | totalgames
oliver| 750         | 2
dave  | 250         | 1
```

I will use this format to do the same with account_name. I have found information on how to group and sum the data but not into a second table. Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you want to take the result of a SELECT, and stuff it into an INSERT? Take a look at the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, create your table by:

```
CREATE TABLE `stats` (
    `name`  TEXT PRIMARY KEY ON CONFLICT REPLACE,
    `totalpoints`   INTEGER,
    `totalgames`    INTEGER
);
```

then insert into your table with:

```
INSERT INTO stats 
SELECT games.name, SUM(games.score) AS totalpoints, COUNT(*) AS totalgames
FROM games
GROUP BY games.name
```

Comment: I had to change the table names, but otherwise, it worked perfectly. Thank you.